# check which button is pressed

Tags: android

I am using Selectors to change the color of some buttons by setting the background of each button to `drawable/selectors.xml`.

When the button is pressed by the user the color of a button changes. But, what if I want to see which button is pressed by the user. How can I put an event to check the click on the Button by the USER.

Comment: use mybutton.isPressed() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your layout have multiple `Button` you need to try to implement [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to find which `Button` clicked.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
private Button button1,button2,button3;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            switch (view.getId())
            {
                //handle multiple view click events
                case R.id.button1:
                Log.e("Which Button click","Button1 is clicked");
                break;
                case R.id.button2:
                Log.e("Which Button click","Button2 is clicked");
                break;
                case R.id.button3:
                Log.e("Which Button click","Button3 is clicked");
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

I hope its help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yo could do something like this using isPressed() method

```
Button myBu= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        myBu.isPressed();// example how to use it
        Log.d("is pressed?", "" + myBu.isPressed());//false, not pressed

        myBu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("is pressed", "" + v.isPressed());//true,pressed
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a View.OnTouchListener like this :

```
mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
      int action = ev.getAction();
      switch(v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button1:
              if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                   mButtonOnePressed = true;
              }
              else if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP||action==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                   mButtonOnePressed = false;
              break;
           ..and so on
      }
      return false;
}
};
```

and for every button :

mButton1.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);

Comment: why do we need to pass MotionEvent object, what is the purpose?

Comment: the MotionEvent object is automatically passed by the view to the listener